# Resolution easy recurrence equation

Tags: time-complexity, recurrence

I have to find the recurrence equation of following function.

```
public static boolean f(int[] a) {
    return fr(a, 0);
}

private static boolean fr(int[] a, int i) {
    int n = a.length;
    if(i >= n-1) 
        return true;
    else if(a[i] > a[i+1]) 
        return false;
    else 
        return fr(a, i+1);
}
```

I think it is:

**T(1) = 1**

**T(n) = T(n - 1)**

Resolving I get the result **T(n) = n**. It's right? It seems strange the resolution of this equation..
Looking at the code it's easy to see that the complexity is **Θ(n)** (runs through the entire array).

It's a stupid question but sends me into confusion.
Thanks to anyone who wants to help me

Comment: What makes you think T(n) = T(n - 1)? Do you somehow think T(2) = T(1) = 1? And if so, Is T(3) = T(2) = T(1) = 1, ... T(n) = 1?

Comment: @Amit T(n) = T(n-1) because the recursive call is performed on the array length minus 1...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
T(1) = O(1)
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(1)
```

This is indeed the signature of a sequential search and it has *O(n)* time complexity. This is because `T(n) = T(n-1)` has *O(n)* complexity and the *O(1)* term drops out.

The solution is trivial:
Say we know `T(n) = T(n-1)`, and we also know that `T(1) = O(1)`. This implies that `T(2) = O(1)` and `T(3) = O(1)` and so forth. So it is just equivalent to `n*O(1)` which is `O(n)`.

Comment: Why aT(n-1) was added O(1)? Is the **return** statement?

Comment: The *O(1)* term comes from the cost of the actual greater-than comparison. You could also conceptually lump in the rest of the function's statements like the `if` and the `return`. As long as they are one-time only statements and their complexity is independent of length `n`, they will all sum to *O(1)*.